# SharePoint Designer 2010 - Conditional Formatting using Hidden Columns -> Inline Editing problem

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, conditional-formatting

I would like to conditionally format some columns based on other hidden columns.  I used the method of cutting the columns that aren't too be displayed that was described here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/b9cee891-2a35-4420-bfbb-5ebf2f3fecfa

Unfortunately, the cut columns still appear when I use Inline Editing.  Is there a way to hide these columns during inline editing too?

I cannot use the DataFormWebPart method described in the link.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by inline editing?

Comment: It's an option with SP2010 that can be enable when a view is created or modified.  It allows for a row of data to be edited without actually calling an editing window/box.  Basically, when it's enabled you can directly edit a row of data in your list.

Answer (score 1):

Inline editing shows the lists that are selected for the view. Modify the view to select only the columns you want to show. Here's a walkthrough of modifying a view from Microsoft:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/create-modify-or-delete-a-view-HA010377693.aspx#_Toc239586331

Comment: Thank you for answering. To be more descriptive, I'm using list data from columns 1-4 to conditionally format columns 5-8. Columns 1-4 contain no useful information for site users, so I want them hidden. Unfortunately SP is inefficient in that to conditionally format columns 5-8, columns 1-4 have to appear in the "view". To get around this, I "cut" columns 1-4 in SP Designer so they are still technically in the view, but can't be seen by site users.  Unfortunately, although columns 1-4 are out of the view, they still appear during inline editing.

Comment: As a work around, I've created 4 new list items and made them calculated columns.  Each is calculated to correspond to columns 1-4.  I displayed these columns in the view and then cut them out in SP Designer.  Inline Editing doesn't allow editing of calculated columns so they don't show up.  It gets the job done, but is an ugly work around.

Answer (score 0):

Could you create a custom content type and set the supporting columns to Hidden? this should keep them hidden when using inline editing.